# How to add a fade or slide effect to a sub menu ul

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to add a Jquery effect or CSS fade/slide to my sub menu but can't seem to get it to work. The ul sub nav is set to display none in my CSS. Then when you click on the 'a' tag with the class dropdown-toggle it adds the class 'display-sub-menu' this child ul (Now, display block in my CSS).  My code is as below;

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav-list">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" title="About Us">About Us</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="about-us.html">About Our Business</a></li>
            <li><a href="meet-the-team.html">Meet The Team</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My Jquery is as follows:

```
$('a.dropdown-toggle').click(function(e) {
    $(this).next().toggleClass('display-sub-menu', 250);
});
```

At present this just hides and displays. There is no effect of slide if I use slideToggle etc

Answer (score 3):

Instead of toggling class, you can use `.fadeToggle()/.slideToggle()` to toggle with fade/slide

also both methods take duration as argument, you can pass 250 as argument:

```
$('a.dropdown-toggle').click(function (e) {
    $(this).next().fadeToggle(250);
});
```

or

```
$('a.dropdown-toggle').click(function (e) {
    $(this).next().slideToggle(250);
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hbyykd68/)**

Comment: This is good, so thanks for the help. However, get a really jumpy effect. It fades in subtle, but then I get a quick snappy collapse after the fade has completed? Thanks :)

Comment: @AlySebastien: you can modify duration parameter as per requirement.

Comment: yep, the slide toggle should be easy but for some reason in doesn't slide in my project. (Although it is fine in the demo link)

Comment: Is there any other script that is affecting those elements?? would be great if you can reproduce the problem in fiddle.

Comment: There must be a gremlin somewhere else, as when I use slideToggle it behave like this http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_show_hide  (no slide just open/close)

Comment: Nah. there has to be a valid explanation.